# nslcd segfaults at start on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, autostart, segmentation-fault

During boot, `nslcd` segfaults with these errors in `syslog`:

```
nslcd: segfault at 10 ip 00007f49c7798404 sp 00007f49c2f85060 error 4
nslcd: segfault at 10 ip 00007f49c7798404 sp 00007f49c2784060 error 4 in libpthread-2.19.so[7f49c778e000+19000]
nslcd: segfault at 10 ip 00007f49c7798404 sp 00007f49c2f85060 error 4
nslcd: segfault at 10 ip 00007f49c7798404 sp 00007f49c2784060 error 4 in libpthread-2.19.so[7f49c778e000+19000]
```

when I restart `nslcd` manually, it starts OK:

```
service nslcd restart
```

So it only seems to crash when started automatically for the first time during boot.

Any ideas what might be causing it?

Comment: have you tried disabling auto start so you can start it manually and observe what is happening closer.  This would allow you to work out if its strictly a first start issue or if its something that is not ready when its being started automatically (and presumably earlier in the sequence than manually.